# Query with pg_total_relation_size ignoring WHERE clause filter

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get the size of the tables in the public schema using the `pg_total_relation_size` method like this:

```sql
SELECT table_name, table_schema, table_catalog,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(table_name)) as table_size
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
```

When I do, I get the error:

```
[42883] ERROR: function pg_total_relation_size(information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 72
```

For some reason, it is trying to use the `pg_total_relation_size` function on the table `information_schema.sql_identifier` even though the `WHERE` clause filters out that entire function.

Indeed, if I run the query:

```sql
SELECT table_name, table_schema, table_catalog
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
```

I can see that `information_schema.sql_identifier` is not included in the result set. If remove the `WHERE` clause I **DO** see `information_schema.sql_identifier`.

The only thing that seems apparent is that the WHERE clause is being ignore for some reason.

How can I make this run as expected and to only return the size of the tables in the PUBLIC scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error actually says:

```
ERROR:  function pg_total_relation_size(information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist
LINE 1: ...name, table_schema, table_catalog, pg_size_pretty(pg_total_r...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

That is a *type* not a column. The function wants a `regclass` not an `sql_identifier`.

```
=> \df pg_total_relation_size
                                   List of functions
┌────────────┬────────────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│   Schema   │          Name          │ Result data type │ Argument data types │ Type │
├────────────┼────────────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────┤
│ pg_catalog │ pg_total_relation_size │ bigint           │ regclass            │ func │
└────────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘
```

You want to call it like

```
... pg_total_relation_size(table_name::regclass)
```